# LiveWire get value from dropdown list

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, livewires

I am unable to get value from a LiveWire dropdown list

this is my dropdown list:

```
<select   wire:model.live="members"   class="form-control">
        <option value="" selected>Select members</option>
        @foreach($members as $key => $member)
            <option value="{{$member}}"  wire:key="members-{{ $key }}"  >{{$assignee}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

this is my component page:

```
class Test extends Component
{
    
    public members;

 public function selectedMembers($members)
    {
        dd($members);
    }
```

Comment: And what's the output of `dd($members);`? What have you tried to resolve the issue?
Please read [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.